# NetSuite Script Works in SANDBOX but not PRODUCTION account

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a very simple NetSuite scrip that sets the value of the externalid when the record is saved. I have done testing on the SB account and it is working as expected. Copying the same configuration into the production account and the script is not executing. I've even added some dialog boxes to see if I can see any activity but there is none. The script is deployed, released and has "all roles" as the audience.
Any ideas what I can do to get the script to work?
Thanks.

Comment: Are there any hard coded values in your script, perhaps ones that are specific to SB environment?

Answer (score 0):

Is your sandbox a very recent copy of Production?  Does it have all the same scripts deployed as there is in production?  You may want to look at the scripted record list for User Event Scripts in both environments, make sure they are the same.

You could also post your code here for us to look at it.

[image]